# Mobile home central air not getting cool enough

Tags: hvac

The refrigerant is full. The blower works good. The coil was recently removed and cleaned. Still only cools to 78 degrees. Only a 980 sq. foot home. The air pressure appears to be the same coming from all of the vents. Has a 2 1/2 ton condenser on it. It cost's $50 per month more to cool it than to heat it.Any suggestions?

Comment: To 78 degrees at the thermostat? Or is the vent output air 78 degrees? What is the outside temperature?

Comment: at the thermostat. 96 degrees outside

Comment: Can you measure the temperature of the air at the vent?

Comment: No. I do not have a way to measure the temperature.

Comment: I will have something tomorrow afternoon. What temperature should be coming from the vents? Also what is the best way to make sure I do not have a ductwork problem?

Comment: I'm not sure (I'm not an HVAC tech.), but I know that the basic concept is that the cold air should come out of the vents quite a bit colder than the thermostat setting - otherwise the A/C will run 100% of the time (which it has probably been doing for you lately). My best guess would be ~ 60 or so but a tech. should know - and should have a infrared thermometer to read it quickly & accurately. As far as ductwork - hard to say - depends a lot on design of the home - i.e., where/how accessible is the ductwork.

Comment: Are you getting a generous volume of air coming out the vents? Is the air coming out cold to your hand or face? Is the compressor cycling off and on or is it staying on during the heat of the day? BTW it is OK for the compressor to stay on continuously for hours on end. This will not harm the compressor. if you go outside to the condensing unit is the larger refrigerant line (the cool gas return to the compressor) cold to the touch? The other one (the smaller one) will be warm to the touch. The smaller one carries liquid refrigerant to the evaporator coil inside.

Comment: It does not seem all that strong and is just cool. The unit runs all of the time unless the thermostat is raised to 78. Any lower it does run all of the time. The large line is cool and the small line is very warm.

Comment: Got shade, or insulation? Either would help. What color is the trailer, and roof? Lighter is better. Is the outside heat exchanger clean, with a good hot flow?

Comment: roof is light brown. color is tan. It was built in Indiana. It only had one roof vent so a couple of weeks I added 5 more but it did not help. I was able to tell that it had a lot of insulation in the attic. I may be wrong but I am leaning toward the duct work leaking. When something happens to the cross over duct in the one I live in, it has the same semptems. The ac runs all of the time then to and it will not cool down.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell for sure without a limit more diagnostic information (e.g., temperature of air at the vents) but this may simply be a limit on the A/C capabilities. According to [How Much Can Your Air Conditioner Cool](https://www.wmhendersoninc.com/blog/air-conditioning-service/how-much-can-an-air-conditioner-cool-realistic-temperature-differences-between-inside-and-outside-air-in-broomall/) a typical differential is ~ 20 degrees. 96 - 78 = 18 degrees. Not quite 20 but not that far off. 2-1/2 tons for 980 square feet mobile home is typical for a hot area.

Assuming that your A/C is working properly, given the outside temperature, the main thing I suggest is checking for leakage. Even small air leaks around doors or windows can have a significant impact on effective cooling capacity.

As far as cooling costing more than heating, that is quite common - in all types of homes.

Comment: This is a small double wide that I have the problem with. I live in a larger double wide next door. My heating bill is usually $50 more per month than the cooling bill. I will check the temperatures tomorrow evening and update my post. Thank you for your answers. I live near Fort Smith Arkansas.

Comment: A properly working 2.5 ton unit (30,000 BTU/h) should be able to cool a small double wide to less than 78 F. Are there trees around the house or is it open to the sun and with pavement or dark soil w/o vegetation close by? 45 years ago in Tallahassee FL we lived in a single wide 12 x 44 ft MH for 5 years surrounded by trees. Our ducts (for heat only no central A/C) were under the floor. We used a single window a/c unit. I can't remember size but was 240 V and at least 12 kBTU/h. It cooled well.

Comment: I have seen some houses (not manufactured) with holes in duct work from possums chewing through the side of soft ducts.

Comment: There was shade last year but the trees had to be cut. The cooling did not work properly last year either. I found a 8 inch plastic flexible duct that was chewed into and fixed it at that section. Because of the vapor barrier it is hard to look at all of the duct work, but the rest appears to be aluminum. I have had to put window units in it for now but would like to get the central ac working properly.

Comment: Probably not aluminum but galvanized steel. Are the central HVAC vents in the floor?

Comment: I did say that wrong. They are metal not aluminum. Yes the vents are in the floor.

Comment: Has anyone ever run into a double wide (not the cross over pipe) that was ran in plastic flex pipe and not all metal duct work. The way the duct work was ran in this house, it connects together where the house joints together and does not have a cross over pipe.